# nuxt class component. async fetch dont work

Tags: vue-component, nuxt.js

```
<script lang="ts">

  import { Vue, Component } from 'vue-property-decorator'
  @Component
  export default class Index extends Vue {
    form = {
      name: '',
      adress: '',
      age: '',
      items: [],
    }


    async fetch() {
      this.form.items = await fetch('https://api.nuxtjs.dev/posts').then(c => c.json())

      console.log(this.form.items)
    }

    fetchOnServer = true;
    changeLanguage(language: string) {
      this.$i18n.setLocale(language);
    }
  }
</script>
```

async fetch dont work in class component

If I use a standard component it works fine. But if I use a class component, the function call stops working.
What is the problem and how can it be fixed

Answer (score 0):

As an annotation argument it works

```
@Component({
  components: {ValidationProvider, ValidationObserver},
  async fetch() {
    console.log('** fetch at ');
    console.log(this.$route);
    await new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
  });
}

})
export default class xrayClient extends Vue {
```

As class methods created() works:

```
async created() {
console.log('** created ');
console.log(this.$route);
await new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
});
```

Mounted() works:

```
async mounted() {
  console.log('** mounted '  + this.data);
   await new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
  });
}
```

Calling

```
async asyncData()
```

and

```
fetch() {
```

Don't run.

"nuxt": "^2.15.7",

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `vue-property-decorator`, you should use [`nuxt-property-decorator`](https://github.com/nuxt-community/nuxt-property-decorator).

Then you can specify your `asyncData` or `fetch` methods in the component options, like this:

```html
<script lang="ts">
  import { Vue, Component } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'
  @Component({
    async fetch() {
      this.form.items = await fetch('https://api.nuxtjs.dev/posts').then(c => c.json())

      console.log(this.form.items)
    }
  })
  export default class Index extends Vue {
    form = {
      name: '',
      adress: '',
      age: '',
      items: [],
    }

    changeLanguage(language: string) {
      this.$i18n.setLocale(language);
    }
  }
</script>
```

See this GitHub issue comment for details: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/5330#issuecomment-475595112